# How do I stop the RuntimeBroker exe from using excessive amounts of CPU?

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage, window

Just upgraded to Windows 10 and my machine is running a lot of CPU!, and this is on an i7

Checked Task Manager and the first culprit looks to be the `RuntimeBroker.exe`

Is there anyway to get this task under control?

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_cortana/runtime-broker-is-using-lot-of-cpu-possibly-due-to/13e54fb0-c567-4cbb-a215-e3ae3b6c93b3

Comment: In my case, disabling the "Show tips on Windows" notification seems to have done the trick. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill Shouldn't you answer my question, so I can give you the upvote?

Comment: I don't really need it. I have no more privileges to earn ;) Feel free to answer yourself ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill Most gracious sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, disabling the "Show tips on Windows" notification seems to have done the trick.

Thanks for the pointer from @DavidPostill

Answer (score -1):

For me the only thing that has worked is stopping sharing media on this PC.

I'll set up sharing what I need later but at least now my CPU wont burn up.